# Is anal sex by accident punishable?

Tags: halal-haram, sex, husband-wife

My question: Is it haram to have anal sex by accident? Will God punish me and my husband for that mistake that we did by accident? (We then stopped at that moment).

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of that question. The other question does not address intentions/accidents.

Comment: @G.Bach — Good point, and if the OP has similar feedback to yours, the question can be re-opened.